# Cut distance between two random graphs

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

I am studying the cut metric from *Large Networks and Graph Limits* by Lovasz and need help proving one of the statements.

On page 128, it says that the cut distance between two independent random graphs on $[n]$ with edge probability $\frac{1}{2}$ is $O(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$, with high probability. Could someone please help me prove this statement in details? Thanks!

Comment: I suspect you have misunderstood the passage (or perhaps that your Question has gotten a bit mangled in the process of editing).  The same sort of question has been asked at MathOverflow (see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/108933/cut-distance-between-two-erdos-renyi-random-graphs)) but the cut-distance claimed is $O(n^{3/2})$ or $\Omega(n^{3/2})$ (per Brendon McKay's answer).  The claim $O(n^{-1/2})$ would imply cut-distances that tend strongly to vanish as $n$ grows without limit.

Comment: Ah, I looked at page 128 [of the manuscript](http://www.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/bookxx/hombook-almost.final.pdf), and the author gives a definition of *cut-distance* that divides by $n^2$.  This resolves the discrepancy with the version discussed at MathOverflow!

Comment: @hardmath Thank you for your comment. The similar question in MathOverflow you have mentioned does not give the proof of this statement.

Comment: It does not give the detailed proof you are looking for, and I will try to find you a good answer.